# How to detect context in Views

Tags: php

I have simple template system for my View, something like:

```
<h2>%var1%</h2>
```

And when I want escape variable i use filter:

```
<h2>%var1|html%</h2>
```

But I want to write "system" to detect context of current variable. System will return html, xml, css or other depending on current context and variable will be correctly escaped.

Can you help me where can I start?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good blog post to start: [Context-aware HTML escaping](http://php.vrana.cz/context-aware-html-escaping.php)
Nette is one framework so far which supports [Context-aware HTML escaping](http://doc.nette.org/en/templating#toc-context-aware-escaping)

Comment: Yeah I know Nette. But I want to write this on my own. I think it will be good challenge :) Thank you!